React App is holding opened audio files, making rename or move of the files on server impossible
What is the best approach in situation like this ...
React App is using audio file from server as a source in HTML5 audio.
As a result it's impossible to do anything with this audio file on server (like rename or move it). Also folder of this file can't be renamed until React App "holding" the file. Even if App is closed, it requires some time to be able to rename folder on server.
How to deal with this, so I would be able to rename folder without waiting?
Backend is Python and I tried dozen of different approaches. Nothing is good enough.
